# Smith normal form and decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

For any square matrix $A$ how to find the Cyclic decomposition and the primary decomposition of a matrix using the Smith normal form??

I need the procedure in general. However, I tried to solve the problem for a specific matrix:
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0&  1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0& 1\end{array} \right]$$

$\star$ I obtained the smith normal form of $xI-A$ $$xI-A \approx \left[\begin{array}{ccc}   (x-1)(x^2-x-1) &0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0& 1\end{array} \right]$$

$\star$ It is very easy to see that $p(x)=(x-1)(x^2-x-1)$ is the invariant factor.

I dont know how to continue to find the Cyclic decomposition and the primary decomposition using the invariant factors??

What happens if the invariant factors are more than one??